# AVFoundation screenRecording issue

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation

Hello I'm trying to use AVFoundation framework to make a screen recored.
And I'v got 2 problems:
1) the recording is starting with a delay after the button is pressed.
2) If I insert breakpoint to throw all the exceptions it get stuck at :

```
[session startRunning];
```

The code is:

```
-(void)initAVRecord{
    session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc]init];
    if ([session canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh]){
        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
    }
    display = CGMainDisplayID();
    captureScreenInput = [[AVCaptureScreenInput alloc]initWithDisplayID:display];
    if ([session canAddInput:captureScreenInput]){
        [session addInput:captureScreenInput];
        NSLog(@"screen device added to session ");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"no screen device added to session");
    }

    audioDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    NSError *error;
    captureAudioInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc]initWithDevice:audioDevice error:&error];
    if ([session canAddInput:captureAudioInput]){
        [session addInput:captureAudioInput];
        NSLog(@"audio device added to session ");
    }else{
        NSLog(@" no audio device added");
    }

    movieOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc]init];
    [movieOutput setDelegate:self];
    if ([session canAddOutput:movieOutput]){
        [session addOutput:movieOutput];
    }
    [session startRunning];
}


- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error
{
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:outputFileURL];
}

-(BOOL)captureOutputShouldProvideSampleAccurateRecordingStart:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput{
    return NO;
}



- (IBAction)recordButton:(id)sender {
    if ([[recordButton title] isEqualToString:@"Record"]){
        [recordButton setTitle:@"Stop"];
        NSLog(@"Minimum Frame Duration: %f, Crop Rect: %@, Scale Factor: %f, Capture Mouse Clicks: %@, Capture Mouse Cursor: %@, Remove Duplicate Frames: %@",
              CMTimeGetSeconds([self.captureScreenInput minFrameDuration]),
              NSStringFromRect(NSRectFromCGRect([self.captureScreenInput cropRect])),
              [self.captureScreenInput scaleFactor],
              [self.captureScreenInput capturesMouseClicks] ? @"Yes" : @"No",
              [self.captureScreenInput capturesCursor] ? @"Yes" : @"No",
              [self.captureScreenInput removesDuplicateFrames] ? @"Yes" : @"No");
        char *tempNameBytes = tempnam([[@"~/Desktop/" stringByStandardizingPath]fileSystemRepresentation],"screenRec1_");
        NSString *tempName = [[NSString alloc]initWithBytesNoCopy:tempNameBytes length:strlen(tempNameBytes) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding freeWhenDone:YES];
        [movieOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[tempName stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"mov"]] recordingDelegate:self];

    }else if ([[recordButton title] isEqualToString:@"Stop"]){
        [recordButton setTitle:@"Record"];
        [movieOutput stopRecording];
    }

}
```

Can someone tells me what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

> The startRunning() method is a blocking call which can take some time, therefore you should perform session setup on a serial queue so that the main queue isn't blocked (which keeps the UI responsive). See [AVCam-iOS: Using AVFoundation to Capture Images and Movies](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112) for an implementation example.

from Apple doc [startrunning](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession/1388185-startrunning)